# Python 3 - utf-8 str to latin character

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I have a string in Python 3.5:

```
In [2]: foo
Out[2]: 'Attila_Szedl%C3%A1k'
```

I would like to turn it to something like

```
In [3]: foo_mod
Out[3]: 'Attila_Szedlák'
```

That is, I want to turn the "á" character's utf-8 code to something that is actually an "á". What is the mapping from `foo` to `foo_mod`?

I have tried

```
In [4]: foo_mod = foo.encode("latin-1")

In [5]: foo_mod
Out[5]: b'Attila_Szedl%C3%A1k'
```

But this is apparently not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That string looks url encoded.  The tool you want is in [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)

```
>>> s
'Attila_Szedl%C3%A1k'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote(s)
'Attila_Szedlák'
```

Comment: Perfect. How do you think I should modify the title of the question?